# In App Browser URL change event not working Ionic Capacitor app for iOS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

We are building a capacitor ionic application to support in app browser functionalities.
The below plugin are been used in. The application

```
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser": "^6.3.0",
```

After the browser load URL change events are working fine on the Android devices , However in the iOS the URL change events are not working. We could see that LoadStart, LoadStop and Load Exist is working, but none of the other events are working.

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser/ngx'; 
@Injectable()
export class IntegrationProvider {
constructor(
private iab: InAppBrowser
) {}

var browser = this.iab.create(redirecturl, '_blank', options);
  browser.on('loadstart').subscribe((event) => {
  console.log('loadstart');
  let retMsg = event.url;
  if (retMsg == 'close') {
    browser.close();
  }
  this.loadstartextLinks(event, options);
});

browser.on('loadstop').subscribe((event) => {
  console.log('loadstop no saml');
  this.loadstartextLinks(event, options);
});

loadstartextLinks(event, options) {
console.log('inside loadstart handler');
 if (
  event.url.includes('tel:') ||
  event.url.includes('mailto:')
 ) {
  this.handleExternalURLs(event);
 }
 if (event.url.includes(‘https://www.google.com/')) {
  this.handleExternalURLs(event);
  this.externalBrowser(url, options);
 }
}
```

}